Hyperledger Fabric TLS Handshake Error When Peers from Different Organizations Join Channel
I am setting up a Hyperledger Fabric network locally using Docker Compose. The network includes multiple organizations, each with its own peers and orderers. I am facing an issue where peers from organizations other than the orderer organization (rtwholefoods) fail to join the channel due to a TLS handshake error.
Network Setup (docker-compose)
Here is the relevant portion of my Docker Compose file for setting up the orderer and peers:
version: '2'

networks:
  wholefoods:

volumes:
  data-orderer.rtwholefoods.com:
  data-peer0.rtwholefoods.com:
  data-peer1.rtwholefoods.com:
  data-peer0.farmerswholesalers.com:
  data-peer1.farmerswholesalers.com:
  # Other volumes...

services:

  orderer.rtwholefoods.com:
    container_name: orderer.rtwholefoods.com 
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    command: orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/tls/ca.crt]
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/config/orderer:/var/hyperledger/config
      - ${PWD}/config/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer.rtwholefoods.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
      - ${PWD}/config/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer.rtwholefoods.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/tls
      - data-orderer.rtwholefoods.com:/var/ledger
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - wholefoods

# 4 more orderers from the same organization..

  # RTwholefoods peer0
  peer0.rtwholefoods.com:
    container_name: peer0.rtwholefoods.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config/peer0
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_wholefoods
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.rtwholefoods.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/peer0/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/peer0/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/peer0/tls/ca.crt
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/config/rtwholefoods/peer0:/var/hyperledger/config/peer0
      # Map the folder with MSP for Peer
      - ${PWD}/config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/peers/peer0.rtwholefoods.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/peer0/msp
      # Added to support the TLS setup
      - ${PWD}/config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/peers/peer0.rtwholefoods.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/peer0/tls
      - /var/run/:/var/run/
      - data-peer0.rtwholefoods.com:/var/hyperledger/production/peer0
    depends_on: 
      - orderer.rtwholefoods.com
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7052:7052
    networks:
      - wholefoods

  peer0.farmerswholesalers.com:
    container_name: peer0.farmerswholesalers.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config/peer0
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_wholefoods
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.farmerswholesalers.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/peer0/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/peer0/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/peer0/tls/ca.crt
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/config/farmerswholesalers/peer0:/var/hyperledger/config/peer0
      - ${PWD}/config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/farmerswholesalers.com/peers/peer0.farmerswholesalers.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/peer0/msp
      - ${PWD}/config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/farmerswholesalers.com/peers/peer0.farmerswholesalers.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/peer0/tls
      - /var/run/:/var/run/
      - data-peer0.farmerswholesalers.com:/var/hyperledger/production/peer0
    depends_on: 
      - orderer.rtwholefoods.com
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9052:7052
    networks:
      - wholefoods

  # Other services...


Problem
When I try to join the channel with peers from organizations other than rtwholefoods, I receive the following error:
2024-06-09 22:53:16.728 +08 0001 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 3.609583ms with error: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for peer0.rtwholefoods.com, peer0, not peer0.farmerswholesalers.com remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:7051


Other Configuration files for reference

configtx.yaml
Organizations:
    - &Orderer
      Name: Orderer
      ID: OrdererMSP
      MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/msp
      Policies:
          Readers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
          Writers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
          Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
          Endorsement:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"

    - &RTWholefoods
      Name: RTWholefoodsMSP
      ID: RTWholefoodsMSP
      MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/msp
      Policies:
          Readers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('RTWholefoodsMSP.member')"
          Writers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('RTWholefoodsMSP.member')"
          Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('RTWholefoodsMSP.admin')"
          Endorsement:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('RTWholefoodsMSP.member')"
      AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.rtwholefoods.com
            Port: 7051

    - &FarmersWholesalers
      Name: FarmersWholesalersMSP
      ID: FarmersWholesalersMSP
      MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/farmerswholesalers.com/msp
      Policies:
          Readers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('FarmersWholesalersMSP.member')"
          Writers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('FarmersWholesalersMSP.member')"
          Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('FarmersWholesalersMSP.admin')"
          Endorsement:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('FarmersWholesalersMSP.member')"
      AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.farmerswholesalers.com
            Port: 7051

    - &Logistics
      Name: LogisticsMSP
      ID: LogisticsMSP
      MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/logistics.com/msp
      Policies:
          Readers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('LogisticsMSP.member')"
          Writers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('LogisticsMSP.member')"
          Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('LogisticsMSP.admin')"
          Endorsement:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('LogisticsMSP.member')"
      AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.logistics.com
            Port: 7051

    - &PaymentPlatform
      Name: PaymentPlatformMSP
      ID: PaymentPlatformMSP
      MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/paymentplatform.com/msp
      Policies:
          Readers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('PaymentPlatformMSP.member')"
          Writers:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('PaymentPlatformMSP.member')"
          Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('PaymentPlatformMSP.admin')"
          Endorsement:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('PaymentPlatformMSP.member')"
      AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.paymentplatform.com
            Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    ACLs: &ACLsDefault

    Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Endorsement"
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft

    Addresses:
        - orderer.rtwholefoods.com:7050

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
            - Host: orderer.rtwholefoods.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt

            - Host: orderer2.rtwholefoods.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer2.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer2.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt

            - Host: orderer3.rtwholefoods.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer3.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer3.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt

            - Host: orderer4.rtwholefoods.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer4.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer4.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt

            - Host: orderer5.rtwholefoods.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer5.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/rtwholefoods.com/orderers/orderer5.rtwholefoods.com/tls/server.crt

        Options:
            TickInterval: 500ms
            ElectionTick: 10
            HeartbeatTick: 1
            MaxInflightBlocks: 5
            SnapshotIntervalSize: 20 MB

    BatchTimeout: 2s

    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512  KB

    Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    RTWholefoodsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *Orderer
        Consortiums:
            WholeFoodsConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - <<: *RTWholefoods
                    - <<: *FarmersWholesalers
                    - <<: *Logistics
                    - <<: *PaymentPlatform
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *RTWholefoods
                - <<: *FarmersWholesalers
                - <<: *Logistics
                - <<: *PaymentPlatform

    SupplyChainChannel:
        Consortium: WholeFoodsConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *RTWholefoods
                - <<: *FarmersWholesalers
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    LogisticsChannel:
        Consortium: WholeFoodsConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *RTWholefoods
                - <<: *Logistics
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    PaymentsChannel:
        Consortium: WholeFoodsConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *RTWholefoods
                - <<: *PaymentPlatform
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities


crypto-config.yaml
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: OrdererOrg
    Domain: rtwholefoods.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
      - Hostname: orderer2
      - Hostname: orderer3
      - Hostname: orderer4
      - Hostname: orderer5

PeerOrgs:
  - Name: RTWholefoods
    Domain: rtwholefoods.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1

  - Name: FarmersWholesalers
    Domain: farmerswholesalers.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1

  - Name: Logistics
    Domain: logistics.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1

  - Name: PaymentPlatform
    Domain: paymentplatform.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1

Orderer.yaml
################################################################################
#
#   Orderer Configuration
#
################################################################################
General:

    BootstrapMethod: file

    BootstrapFile: /var/hyperledger/config/genesis_block.pb

    # BCCSP Setup
    BCCSP:
        # Setup to use the Software CSP
        Default: SW
        SW:
            HASH: SHA2
            Security: 256
            # Using the default 'LocalMSPDir/keystore'
            FileKeyStore:
                Keystore:

    # Directory for the private crypto material needed by the
    # orderer. 
    LocalMSPDir: /var/hyperledger/msp

    # Identity to register the local MSP material with the MSP
    LocalMSPID: OrdererMSP

    # Listen address: The IP on which to bind to listen.
    ListenAddress: 0.0.0.0

    # Listen port: The port on which to bind to listen.
    ListenPort: 7050

    # Used orderer type = etcdraft
    Cluster:
        # SendBufferSize is the maximum number of messages in the egress buffer.
        # Consensus messages are dropped if the buffer is full, and transaction
        # messages are waiting for space to be freed.
        SendBufferSize: 10
        # ClientCertificate governs the file location of the client TLS certificate
        # used to establish mutual TLS connections with other ordering service nodes.
        ClientCertificate:
        # ClientPrivateKey governs the file location of the private key of the client TLS certificate.
        ClientPrivateKey:
        # The below 4 properties should be either set together, or be unset together.
        # If they are set, then the orderer node uses a separate listener for intra-cluster
        # communication. If they are unset, then the general orderer listener is used.
        # This is useful if you want to use a different TLS server certificates on the
        # client-facing and the intra-cluster listeners.

        # ListenPort defines the port on which the cluster listens to connections.
        ListenPort:
        # ListenAddress defines the IP on which to listen to intra-cluster communication.
        ListenAddress:
        # ServerCertificate defines the file location of the server TLS certificate used for intra-cluster
        # communication.
        ServerCertificate:
        # ServerPrivateKey defines the file location of the private key of the TLS certificate.
        ServerPrivateKey:

    # Keepalive settings for the GRPC server.
    Keepalive:
        # Disconnect the client if the time between pings is less than the specified time
        ServerMinInterval: 60s
        # Server pings the clients on open connection with the specified time between pings
        ServerInterval: 7200s
        # Server expects the clients to respond to pings. Server disconnets if response not receieved within timeout
        ServerTimeout: 20s

    # TLS: TLS settings for the GRPC server.
    TLS:
        Enabled: false
        PrivateKey: ./server.key
        Certificate: ./server.crt
        RootCAs:
          - ./ca.crt
        ClientAuthRequired: false
        ClientRootCAs:


################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: File Ledger
#   - This section applies to the configuration of the file or json ledgers.
################################################################################
FileLedger:

    # Location: The directory to store the blocks in.
    # Windows - if you get a LevelDb error in launching orderer use the VM file 
    # by uncommenting the following line - comment the Location: ./ledger 
    Location: /var/ledger

    # The prefix to use when generating a ledger directory in temporary space.
    Prefix: hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger    



################################################################################
#
#   Debug Configuration
#
#   - This controls the debugging options for the orderer
#
################################################################################
Debug:

    # BroadcastTraceDir when set will cause each request to the Broadcast service
    # for this orderer to be written to a file in this directory

    # BroadcastTraceDir: ./trace
    BroadcastTraceDir: 

    # DeliverTraceDir when set will cause each request to the Deliver service
    # for this orderer to be written to a file in this directory

    # DeliverTraceDir: ./trace
    DeliverTraceDir:


################################################################################
#
#   Operations Configuration
#
#   - This configures the operations server endpoint for the orderer
#
################################################################################
Operations:
    # host and port for the operations server
    ListenAddress: 127.0.0.1:8443

    # TLS configuration for the operations endpoint
    TLS:
        # TLS enabled
        Enabled: false

        # Certificate is the location of the PEM encoded TLS certificate
        Certificate:

        # PrivateKey points to the location of the PEM-encoded key
        PrivateKey:

        # Require client certificate authentication to access all resources
        ClientAuthRequired: false

        # Paths to PEM encoded ca certificates to trust for client authentication
        RootCAs: []

################################################################################
#
#   Metrics  Configuration
#
#   - This configures metrics collection for the orderer
#
################################################################################
Metrics:
    # The metrics provider is one of statsd, prometheus, or disabled
    Provider: disabled

    # The statsd configuration
    Statsd:
      # network type: tcp or udp
      Network: udp

      # the statsd server address
      Address: 127.0.0.1:8125

      # The interval at which locally cached counters and gauges are pushed
      # to statsd; timings are pushed immediately
      WriteInterval: 30s

      # The prefix is prepended to all emitted statsd metrics
      Prefix:


################################################################################
# Used for orderer type = etcdraft
################################################################################
Consensus:
    # The allowed key-value pairs here depend on consensus plugin. For etcd/raft,
    # we use following options:

    # WALDir specifies the location at which Write Ahead Logs for etcd/raft are
    # stored. Each channel will have its own subdir named after channel ID.
    WALDir: /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal

    # SnapDir specifies the location at which snapshots for etcd/raft are
    # stored. Each channel will have its own subdir named after channel ID.
    SnapDir: /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot

What I've Tried

Verified that the TLS certificates and keys are correctly configured and mapped in the Docker Compose file.

Regenerated the certificates using the cryptogen tool to ensure they are correctly issued.

Ensured that the FABRIC_CFG_PATH and other environment variables are set correctly for each service.



Does this have to do with the ca of rtwholefoods not trusting the ca of the other orgs?

Issue resolved:
Turns out, i was using the wrong port number,
both my organization peer0:
peer0.rtwholefoods.com
peer0.logistics.com
were both configured to be at port 7051 as there were in separate docker containers.
but if I were to call them through my own terminal, I should be using the ports that was forwarded as stated in my docker compose file.
It was a port conflict issue and this is resolved.
